# How to scrape content from a complex div class using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I'm making some exercises to practice web scraping using Python and I would like to get the values of the first row ("Total Revenue") of the table of [this Yahoo page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAC/financials?p=BAC) ([Bank of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_of_America) at [NYSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Stock_Exchange)).

Looking at the page source, my idea is to find the first occurrence of `<div class="" data-test="fin-row">` and get the values but I'm not sure how to navigate inside the first div.

Below I present the HTML code where the first row is presented:

```html
<div class="" data-test="fin-row">
    <div class="D(tbr) fi-row Bgc($hoverBgColor):h">
        <div class="D(tbc) Ta(start) Pend(15px)--mv2 Pend(10px) Bxz(bb) Py(8px) Bdends(s) Bdbs(s) Bdstarts(s) Bdstartw(1px) Bdbw(1px) Bdendw(1px) Bdc($seperatorColor) Pos(st) Start(0) Bgc($lv2BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) Pstart(15px)--mv2 Pstart(10px)">
            <div class="D(ib) Va(m) Ell Mt(-3px) W(215px)--mv2 W(200px) undefined" title="Total Revenue">
                <button aria-label="Total Revenue" class="P(0) M(0) Va(m) Bd(0) Fz(s) Mend(2px) tgglBtn">
                    <svg class="H(16px) Fill($primaryColor) Stk($primaryColor) tgglBtn:h_Fill($linkColor) tgglBtn:h_Stk($linkColor) Cur(p)" width="16" style="stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom" height="16" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-icon="caret-right">
                        <path d="M33.447 24.102L20.72 11.375c-.78-.78-2.048-.78-2.828 0-.78.78-.78 2.047 0 2.828l9.9 9.9-9.9 9.9c-.78.78-.78 2.047 0 2.827.78.78 2.047.78 2.828 0l12.727-12.728z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <span class="Va(m)">Total Revenue</span>
            </div>
            <div class="W(3px) Pos(a) Start(100%) T(0) H(100%) Bg($pfColumnFakeShadowGradient) Pe(n) Pend(5px)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>90,742,000</span></div>
        <div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>89,113,000</span></div>
        <div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>85,528,000</span></div>
        <div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>91,244,000</span></div>
        <div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>91,247,000</span></div>
    </div>

    <div></div>
```

In my code I'm using Selenium to process the page. Not sure if its the best way but with other libraries like urlopen I wasn't able to see the HTML content. I'm able to open the page, click the accept button, but after that I'm not sure how to navigate inside the first div. I'm actually getting an error like: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"

```python
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAC/financials?p=BAC"
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Click accept button
aceitar = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "agree")
aceitar.click()

# Find the div of the Revenue row <div class="" data-test="fin-row">
primeiraLinha = soup.find("div", {"class":""})
print(primeiraLinha.get_text())
```

BTW, I think Selenium make this process very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Selenium solution to get the entire table in a pandas dataframe.

##### Imports required

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
```

##### Start web driver

```
# Replace your CHROME DRIVER path here
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

##### Fetch the page

```
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAC/financials?p=BAC')
```

##### Wait for table to load

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="D(tbhg)"]')))
```

##### Get the header row

```
headers_elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="D(tbhg)"]/div/div')
col_headers = [header.text for header in headers_elem]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_headers)
df
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Breakdown, TTM, 12/30/2021, 12/30/2020, 12/30/2019, 12/30/2018]
Index: []
```

##### Get the rows from the table

Here each row in the table is stored in `rows`

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="D(tbrg)"]//div[@data-test="fin-row"]')
for row in rows:
    row_values = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'div/div')
    df.loc[len(df)] = [row_value.text for row_value in row_values]
```

##### Output:

Which gives us the expected output:

|  | Breakdown | TTM | 12/30/2021 | 12/30/2020 | 12/30/2019 | 12/30/2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Total Revenue | 90,742,000 | 89,113,000 | 85,528,000 | 91,244,000 | 91,247,000 |
| 1 | Credit Losses Provision | 560,000 | 4,594,000 | -11,320,000 | -3,590,000 | -3,282,000 |
| 2 | Non Interest Expense | 59,763,000 | 59,731,000 | 55,213,000 | 54,900,000 | 53,381,000 |
| 3 | Special Income Charges | - | - | - | - | 0 |
| 4 | Pretax Income | 31,539,000 | 33,976,000 | 18,995,000 | 32,754,000 | 34,584,000 |
| 5 | Tax Provision | 3,521,000 | 1,998,000 | 1,101,000 | 5,324,000 | 6,437,000 |
| 6 | Net Income Common Stockholders | 26,565,000 | 30,557,000 | 16,473,000 | 25,998,000 | 26,696,000 |
| 7 | Diluted NI Available to Com Stockholders | 26,565,000 | 30,557,000 | 16,473,000 | 25,998,000 | 26,696,000 |
| 8 | Basic EPS | - | 3.60 | 1.88 | 2.77 | 2.64 |
| 9 | Diluted EPS | - | 3.57 | 1.87 | 2.75 | 2.61 |
| 10 | Basic Average Shares | - | 8,493,300 | 8,753,200 | 9,390,500 | 10,096,500 |
| 11 | Diluted Average Shares | - | 8,558,400 | 8,796,900 | 9,442,900 | 10,236,900 |
| 12 | INTEREST_INCOME_AFTER_PROVISION_FOR_LOAN_LOSS | 47,080,000 | 47,528,000 | 32,040,000 | 45,301,000 | 44,150,000 |
| 13 | Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation | 28,018,000 | 31,978,000 | 17,894,000 | 27,430,000 | 28,147,000 |
| 14 | Normalized Income | 28,018,000 | 31,978,000 | 17,894,000 | 27,430,000 | 28,147,000 |
| 15 | Total Money Market Investments | 348,000 | -90,000 | 903,000 | 4,843,000 | 3,176,000 |
| 16 | Reconciled Depreciation | 1,953,000 | 1,898,000 | 1,843,000 | 1,729,000 | 2,063,000 |
| 17 | Net Income from Continuing Operation Net Minority Interest | 28,018,000 | 31,978,000 | 17,894,000 | 27,430,000 | 28,147,000 |
| 18 | Total Unusual Items Excluding Goodwill | - | - | - | - | 0 |
| 19 | Total Unusual Items | - | - | - | - | 0 |
| 20 | Tax Rate for Calcs | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 21 | Tax Effect of Unusual Items | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

### TL:DR

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAC/financials?p=BAC')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="D(tbhg)"]')))

headers_elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="D(tbhg)"]/div/div')
col_headers = [header.text for header in headers_elem]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_headers)

rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="D(tbrg)"]//div[@data-test="fin-row"]')
for row in rows:
    row_values = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'div/div')
    df.loc[len(df)] = [row_value.text for row_value in row_values]
```

The result is stored in *df*.

Comment: Thank you! it worked beautiful! Sorry for the delay